# Passing parameter in the fancybox close function

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Is there a way pass parameters from the $.fancybox.close() function and read that parameter in the OnClosed event?

something like this:

```
$("#id_div").fancybox({
         'width': '40%',
         'height': '40%',
         'autoScale': false,
         'transitionIn': 'none',
         'transitionOut': 'none',
         'type': 'iframe',
         'onClosed': function (parameter) {
         alert(parameter);}
    });

$.fancybox.close("parameter")
```

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can achieve the same thing with a variable.

If you wrap your code inside `$(document).ready()`, then something like this should work:

```
$(function(){
    var closedParam;

    $("#id_div").fancybox({
        'width': '40%',
        'height': '40%',
        'autoScale': false,
        'transitionIn': 'none',
        'transitionOut': 'none',
        'type': 'iframe',
        'onClosed': function (currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
            // Use closedParam here
        }
    });

    //  In some other function
    closedParam = ... ;
    $.fancybox.close();
});
```

Comment: I don't have both the functions(.close() and fancybox() ) within the same scope and I do not want to create a global variable.

Comment: Then no, there's no way short of modifying the fancybox plugin code.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use a global variable use an attribute of a hidden or not DOM object.